# Python class returning multiple instances

Tags: python, oop

I'm musing over the design of a class. Currently, I have a list comprehension over a list of data that instantiates an instance of the class on each member of the list, thus returning me a list of instances of my class.

Would it be better, or indeed possible, to have instead a class method that takes a list and returns a list of instances?

Essentially, I'm wondering, would:

```
data = [lots of data]
[MyClass(point) for point in data]
```

or

```
@classmethod
def from_list(cls, data_list):
    return [cls(point) for point in data_list]
```

be better/more pythonic? If it matters, in the usage I intend, I will always be instantiating the class from a list of data.

Comment: "If it matters, in the usage I intend, I will always be instantiating the class from a list of data." - this seems **extremely** likely to change, and then you'll have an awkward class method lying around that handles 75% of use cases and doesn't really make your code cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would argue that the first method would be better (list comprehension) since you will always be initializing the data from a list. This makes things explicit.

Comment: Both choices have the same behavior regardless of what kind of iterable is provided. Why would you prefer the class method (named `from_list`, incidentally) for cases when the data might not come from a list?

Comment: Simply because its more explicit.

Comment: Seems less explicit to me. `MyClass.from_list(set(whatever))` would make me spend a few minutes checking whether that was a bug.

Comment: Come to think of it, you're right. `MyClass.from_list` sends the wrong signal.

Answer (score 0):

As it stands, there isn't much to choose between them. However, the `@classmethod` has one major plus point; it is available to subclasses of `MyClass`. This is far more Pythonic than having separate functions for each type of object you might instantiate in a list.

Comment: More pythonic than having separate functions for each type, but I'd say still no more Pythonic than using list comprehensions.

Comment: Both versions use list comprehensions!